# I can't run project from localhost

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, wampserver

I have a project that I need to edit. To see this project, I wanted to run it on localhost and ran it from **wamp**. Later, when I entered localhost, I got the error.

On top of that, I wanted to run it from **cmd** and see it. The response I got at that time was as follows.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
 thrown in C:\wamp64\www\artisan on line 18
```

Comment: How did you get this project onto your local machine? Looks like you probably need to execute `composer install`, to make it fetch all the dependencies.

Comment: @CBroe I clone the project from Github to the folder.

Comment: Repositories normally don't contain the code of the external dependencies directly - so you need to install them, presumably via composer in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if there is any /vendor/autoload.php file in your wamp folder if not try `composer install` in the terminal where your project is located. (if you don't have composer install the composer first via this [url](https://getcomposer.org/))

you can start your project directly with `php artisan serve` too. if php is added to your windows path variables.

Comment: I have composer installed on my computer. Should I run ```composer install``` then? Also, I could not see the vendor/autoload file in the project. Do I need to get it?

Comment: the `composer install` comand will generate the files in vendor folder you dont need to worry. vendor folders and files are for depenedcys for your laravel and packages you install. people dont upload them in github , they fetch it in ther pc with composer

Comment: I ran the ```composer install``` command as you said and it downloaded the necessary stuff. Now when I run the ```php artisan serve``` command it works fine, but when I open localhost it is gives ```500 | Server Error```. But we solved the problem in the question I asked, after that is another matter. Thank you so much.

Comment: note : `php artisan serve` runs your project in 8000 port by defualt , empty localhost refers to port 80 , try loaclhost:8000 in your browser

Comment: OK, I'll try. :)